# How to improve graphics quality

Tags: qt, graphics, qml

First look at the difference:

[image]

The top's been created in WPF and the bottom with Qt. All Path Data has been taken from [materialdesignicons](http://materialdesignicons.com/). For WPF I've taken `XAML` and for QtQuick `SVG`. For `DropShadow` I've specified a value for `samples` property BUT for svg and rotated `Text` there's no such property.

Is this the difference between OpenGL/CL/etc. and DirectX or something else? The machine I'm working on has both Intel and NVIDIA! I want my QtQuick app to use NVIDIA to compute efficiently and render properly BUT don't know yet how to set that as well as other necessary options application wide to improve quality.

[Here](https://github.com/EmonHaque/QuickTest) is my QtQuick project. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62680102/customizing-window-with-pathsvg) I'd added a sample `qml`file earlier, that shows the way I integrated SVGs in my app.

**EDIT**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895449/how-do-i-enable-antialiasing-on-qml-shapes) actually improves the quality BUT it still is blurry and not as good as it is in WPF. The rotated text has some pointy edges as well.

[image]

With that `QSurfaceFormat` in `main.cpp`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setSamples(15);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    ...
}
```

I don't have to set samples for `DropShadow`. How to enable NVIDIA globally?

**EDIT**

In addition to that I've tried with `QSurfaceFormat::OpenVG` BUT it complains about the driver and wants 3 DLLs in executable folder as an alternative so I've downloaded those 3 DLL and put those in the output directory BUT it still doesn't work! Here's the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Please do not resize the image in QML. The quality will drop. If you need 30x30 image then use 30x30. Don't resize in qml

Comment: it's  24x24 and I'm using same width and height in my custom component

Comment: I have never used SVG in Qml. But png always worked fine for me

Comment: Add the code how you integrate the SVGs. It shouldn't be that pixelated, tweaking should not be necessary. Which platform are you testing on?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, I've uploaded the project as a `.zip` file, link in the EDIT section. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Probably you should post a sample qml file and a sample image resource to check

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, to make the icons crisp, instead of hardcoding it, you have to make it relative to the screen size. Check this link here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976644/how-to-make-svg-icons-crisp-again-in-qt-5-6-on-high-dpi-screens if it helps

Comment: @Chilarai, it's string not image.

Comment: I have tried to scale your svg paths. It seems a little pixelated. Can you fix that  `path: "M 240 40 C 350.457031 40 440 129.542969 440 240 C 440 350.457031 350.457031 440 240 440 C 129.542969 440 40 350.457031 40 240 C 40 129.542969 129.542969 40 240 40 M 220 140 C 197.910156 140 180 157.910156 180 180 L 180 340 L 220 340 L 220 260 L 260 260 L 260 340 L 300 340 L 300 180 C 300 157.910156 282.089844 140 260 140 L 220 140 M 220 180 L 260 180 L 260 220 L 220 220 Z M 220 180`

Comment: @Chilarai, yes it is without any transformation, scaling up will make it obvious. I'm new to QtQuick world, don't know that much, just exploring the Qt way of doing things. Right now I am trying to understand Qt way of two way binding.